# Need help with this limit that wasn't explained well.

Tags: limits

May have missed an obvious argument here but an exam paper I saw evaluated the limit  as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{x^{6n+6}}{6n+6} =0$$

How did they reach such a conclusion?

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x^{6n+6}}{6n+6}$?

Comment: Can it be that there is the condition: |x| < 1?

Comment: I actually depends on the domain of $x$

Comment: I just realised 0<x<1, didn't pickup on that one.

Answer (score 2):

I think that we have $|x| \le 1.$ For $m \in \mathbb N$ consider the sequence $(a_m)=(\frac{x^m}{m})$

Then $|a_m| \le \frac{1}{m}$ . Hence $a_m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty.$

The sequence $(\frac{x^{6n+6}}{6n+6})$ is a subsequence of $(a_m)$.